# PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have `Node v4.1.1`, `npm v2.14.4`, `Karma version: 0.13.15`and following this tutorial http://mcgivery.com/unit-testing-ionic-app/ to test my IONIC Application.

I am getting this error when I am trying to run a test

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
  at D:/IONIC/ionic-testing/www/js/app.js:8
```

Plese help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you actually load "angular" in the `files` and it is the first file to be provided in the list:

```
files: [
  '../www/lib/angular/angular.js',  // make sure this path is the first one and is a valid one
  '../www/js/*.js',
  '../www/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  '**/*tests.js'
],
```

Comment: it works but now it stuck on 

D:\IONIC\ionic-testing>karma start tests/my.conf.js

21 12 2015 10:36:11.099:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/

21 12 2015 10:36:11.112:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.15 server started at http://localhost:9876/

21 12 2015 10:36:11.121:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS

21 12 2015 10:36:11.692:INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket luW9zV-AD5tFZOkjAAAA with id 35298571